# AVLCj MediaListPlayer with rtp Stream and still images

Tags: java, rtp, vlcj

I have a media list player with 2 files in the list. A .jpg file and an .mp4 file.
Both the image and video files play properly when running without args (a player windows displays in server).
But when acting as a sever for an rtp stream, the video does show but the image does not.
I presume this has to do with the arguments being passed.

```
            String[] args =  {
                    ":sout=#rtp{dst=" + 192.168.1.170 + ",port=" + 8554 +",mux=ts, sdp=sap}",
                    ":sout-keep",
                    ":no-sout-all",
                    ":no-sout-audio",
            };
            String[] args2 =  {
                    ":sout=#rtp{dst=" + 192.168.1.170 + ",port=" + 8554 +",mux=ts}",
                    ":image-duration=120.00",
            };
            mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
            photoPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newMediaListPlayer();
            mediaList = mediaPlayerFactory.media().newMediaList();
            mediaList.media().add("picturesVideo.mp4", args);
            mediaList.media().add("image.jpg", args2);
            mediaListRef = mediaList.newMediaListRef();
            photoPlayer.list().setMediaList(mediaListRef);
            photoPlayer.controls().play(0);
```

Comment: Any errors/warnings in the console output?

Comment: Only possibly relevant logs are these:

`[000002392f32fd10] main mux error: cannot add this stream
[000002392f2e09f0] stream_out_rtp stream out error: cannot add this stream to the muxer
[000002392f34fab0] main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (RV24)
[000002392f34fab0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented`

Comment: I suspect you have to transcode the image(s) to a video, I don't know the details.